# add new rate column base previous column

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to add a rate column base on row before current row, just like a diff() but need do some calculation just like below:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.random((5,2)),columns=['v1','v2'])
print(df)

rate = []
rate.append(0)
prev = 0
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if index == 0:
        prev = row
        continue
            
    r = (prev['v2'] - row['v2'])/(row['v1'] - prev['v1'])
    prev = row
    rate.append(r)
        
df['rate'] = rate

print(df)
```

Current logic works what's more better way to do it in python?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the [pandas shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas.DataFrame.shift) function.

```
df['rate'] = (df['v2'] - df['v2'].shift(1)) / (df['v1'].shift(1) - df['v1'])
df['rate'].iloc[0] = 0
df['rate'] = df['rate'].fillna(0)
```

The `shift()` method is used to shift the data by one row, which allows you to easily calculate differences between the current row and the previous row using vectorized operations.

The `.iloc[0]` method is then used to set the rate for the first row to 0.

Comment: what if there are Nan values on other rows than the first one ? the solution only sets the first row rate to 0

Comment: `df['rate'] = df['rate'].fillna(0)` We can use `fillna` function

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but try:

```
df['rate'] = df['v2'].diff().div(df['v1'].diff()).mul(-1).fillna(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

This will calculate rate based on previous row index and **set Nan to 0 (Zero) whenever there is an ocurrence**:

```
df['rate']=((df['v2'].shift(1)-df['v2'])/(df['v1']-df['v1'].shift(1))).fillna(0)
```

Further info for [shift](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html#pandas-dataframe-shift) function.